# How to add using statement in executescalar statement

Tags: c#, database, using-statement

How to add a using statement in following statement

```
this.OpenConnection();
SqlParameter[] SqlParameters = {new SqlParameter("@a",A)};
return Convert.ToLong(  SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar((SqlConnection)DatabaseConnection, "StoredprocName",SqlParameters).ToString());
```

Comment: Why doesn't `SqlHelper` manage opening the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example From MSDN, hope this would help :

```
static public int AddProductCategory(string newName, string connString)
{
    Int32 newProdID = 0;
    string sql =
        "INSERT INTO Production.ProductCategory (Name) VALUES (@Name); "
        + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = newName;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            newProdID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return (int)newProdID;
}
```

More about SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar Method () : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I can't initialize the database connection here , it is been initialized in some other library .

Comment: I just found that you may not be able to use sqlHelper as you show in your code. Here is MSDN information about sqlHelper : 

_This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code._

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlhelpers(v=vs.110).aspx